# TemplateDoesNotExist at

Tags: python, django

Доброго времени суток! Сделал проект по образцу старого ( версии Джанго одинаковые ) 
Но появляется ошибка `TemplateDoesNotExist at`

Конфиг файл:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
```

В `INSTALLED_APPS` приложение подключено

Сама папка `templates` лежит по пути:

- test_site

  - templates
  - manage.py

Так же `views` код:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
return render(request, 'blog/index.html')
```

Файл с именем индекс лежит по пути -

- test_site

  - manage.py
  - templates

    - blog

      - index.html

Comment: Версия Django какая?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev 1.11

Comment: В 1.11 нет настройки `TEMPLATE_DIR`. Её функцию уже давно выполняет ключ `DIRS` словаря `TEMPLATES`.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev добавил вот такое  `'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR],` Но все равно ошибка осталась прежней. Полный путь вручную тоже не помог

Answer (score 2):

Вдруг поможет:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
           'context_processors': [
               'django.template.context_processors.debug',
               'django.template.context_processors.request',
               'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
               'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

А сам файл настроек, находится по дефолту? К примеру если он расположен внутри модуля `settings.py`, то надо добавить еще один уровень к BASE_DIR:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
```

P.S.: добавьте еще данные про `urls.py`, и напоследок еще раз проверьте названия :)

Answer (score -1):

Если вдруг Вам не помог метод, описанный выше, то попробуйте вставить в [DIR] следующее:

```
os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__) , 'templates').replace('\\','/')
```

Это сработало.

Comment: Разве не в `[BASE_DIR]`?

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [справке](/help/how-to-ask).